# == true evaluated but not used

Tags: go, syntax

Inside the code, I try to do some operations

```
is_html := false;

// Check, if HTMl is exist 
for i := 0; i < len(modules_arr); i++ { 
    if modules_arr[i] == "html" { is_html := true }

}

if is_html ==true
{
    fmt.Printf("%v", "asdasd")
}
```

But I get an error:

```
./api.go:26: missing condition in if statement
./api.go:26: is_html == true evaluated but not used
Error: process exited with code 2.
```

Comment: please format your code correctly first using `go fmt`.

Comment: `is_html := true ` shoudl be `is_html = true` notice the lack of a `:`

Comment: I have rolled back the edit to this question that changed the formatting, because the question went away when he fixed the formatting.

Answer (score 13):

if statements needs the { on the same line in go

This means you cannot do

```
if is_html ==true
{
    fmt.Printf("%v", "asdasd")
}
```

The correct code is

```
if is_html ==true {
    fmt.Printf("%v", "asdasd")
}
```

Read http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#semicolons for a better understanding

Also if checking if MyVal == true, you can use the short version:

```
if MyVal{
    //do stuff
}
```

Also in your case, the correct naming would be : IsHtml. You can use golint to print out style mistakes: https://github.com/golang/lint

Example of using golint : https://www.golangprograms.com/media/wysiwyg/name.JPG

Answer (score 2):

For example,

```
package main

func main() {
    modules_arr := []string{"asd", "html"}
    is_html := false

    for i := 0; i < len(modules_arr); i++ {
        if modules_arr[i] == "html" {
            is_html = true
        }

    }
    //or
    for _, value := range modules_arr {
        if value == "html" {
            is_html = true
        }
    }

    if is_html {//<- the problem is here! We Can't move this bracket to the next line without errors, but we can leave the expression's second part
        print("its ok.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    modules_arr := []string{"net", "html"}
    is_html := false
    // Check, if HTMl is exist
    for i := 0; i < len(modules_arr); i++ {
        if modules_arr[i] == "html" {
            is_html = true
        }
    }
    if is_html == true {
        fmt.Printf("%v", "asdasd")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
asdasd
```

The statement `is_html := true` declared a new variable, hiding the variable declared in the statement `is_html := false`. Write `is_html = true` to use the previously declared variable.

Comment: Using `:=` by mistake instead of `=` is a nasty gotcha that can be difficult to detect (fortunatly the compiler refuses if the "new variable" is never read). See for example http://go-traps.appspot.com/#collatz-conjecture

Answer (score 1):

As @Dustin already indicated, it should be `isHtml`.

https://play.golang.org/p/Whr4jJs_ZQG

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    isHtml := false

    if isHtml {
        fmt.Println("isHtml is true")
    }

    if !isHtml {
        fmt.Println("isHtml is false")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In golang what ever you declared you need to use . so,

```
if is_html == true {
    fmt.Printf("%T", is_html)
}
```